# What's easiest way to get nas to mount in12.04

Tags: 12.04, samba, nas

Still fighting to get my nas (dlink) to mount in 12.04, same message as most other folks I see, I've tried a bunch of fstab stuff and i've tried to use samba, not getting it. Is there a step by step for this yet, I can see it, and the files with upnp inspector but cannot play any thing I'm getting desperate!

The nas was setup with my win 7 computer but that computer blew up so got a new one, installed 12.04 on it, the only other computer on the network is my XP laptop, the nas shows up when I browse network by itself and in my windows network icon too but still get the unable to mount location - failure to retrieve share list from server message. I've installed samba thru the software cente, and the nas is at 192.168.1.102 called dlink-034273 and the shared folder is called Volume_1

When I go to the address of the nas in a browser the login screen is setup as admin and I dont put a passwrd or username in, just click login and I get all the nas management

Answer (score 1):

first check if the share is there:

```
smbtree
```

then create a file /home/user/.smb

```
username=winuser
password=winpwd
```

run:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/Volume_1
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/user/.smb //192.168.1.102/Volume_1 /mnt/Volume_1
```

Comment: I seem to be able to mount directories with `sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/user/.smb //<IP>/<folder> /mnt/Volume_1`. Yet that is requiring manual edits. Etc. for each dir I need to specify which folder to mount and access it with dir name in Files>Connect to Server. If I need to access another dir, then I need to umount it before I mount the other dir. I need a better way to pre mount all dirs, so I don't need to manually do it. [Link to my question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/458185/permission-denial-connecting-to-nas)

Comment: The credentials in the `.smb` file are in plain text. Is there a way to crypt the passwd?

Comment: Do I need to do something to include our own domain which isn't WORKGROUP in the `.smb` file?

Comment: you can pass username and password through command line instead of through file. Also you can create a set of different files with credentials and use different mount points - in that way you can have all paths mounted simultaneously. You can't encrypt passwords (as far as I know), but you can make passwords owned by root and set permissions like 600 - files to be visible only by root. For the domain - you don't need to add anything